# Ckeditor 5 removing line-breaks from copying data

Tags: copy-paste, line-breaks, ckeditor5

I use classic default ckeditor 5 build.

The problem is if I copy from notepad text like:

```
1
2
3
```

In editor I give result:

```
1 2 3
```

If I copy next text:

```
1

2

3
```

In editor I give:

```
1
2
3
```

Why ckeditor removing one line-break per line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered something that can be considered a bug or a missing feature.

Single `\n` line characters, which are converted to `<br>` on paste are lost due the fact that CKEditor 5 doesn't support soft-line breaks yet.

On the other hand, not everyone need to load the soft-line break feature so, even if we'll introduce it, the problem will occur for these users. Hance, perhaps the plain text to HTML conversion should work differently. Or be configurable.

More info https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/766